# Intuition of Kolmogorov equations and infinitesimal generators

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

So if we have the infinitesimal generator of a Markov process $\{X_t\}_{t\geq0}$, the infinitesimal generator is given by $$Af(x) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{t} \big(P_tf(x) - f(x)\big)$$ where $P_tf(x) = \mathbb{E}[f(X_t)|X_0 = x]$. Then the Kolmogorov forward equation is the PDE

$$KFE: \begin{cases}\frac{\partial }{\partial t}u(t,x) &= Au(t,x)\\
u(0,x) &= f(x)
\end{cases}$$

which is satisfied by $u(t,x) = \mathbb{E}[f(X_t)|X_0 = x]$.

My understanding is that $Af(x)$ is like the "expected derivative" wrt $t$ of $f(X_t)$, i.e. the expected infinitesimal change in $f(X_t)$.

So why is KFE interesting or important? Doesn't it just restate that $AP_tf(x)$ is the time derivative of $P_tf(x)$ which is true by definition? And what exactly is the implication?

Also: I understand that for diffusion processes like Brownian motion, $A$ resembles the Laplacian operator so KFE is the heat equation. Intuitively, diffusion with an initial condition of $f(x)$ would basically flatten out $f(x)$, so this means the expected value of $f(B_t)$ decreases over time. But for symmetric Brownian motion, shouldn't $P_tf(x) = f(x)$ for all $t$?

Comment: $f(B_t)$ is not going to decrease on average most of the time, consider $f(x)=x^2$ for instance. Anyway, I have not seen many applications where you actually want to compute $P_t f$. The applications I have seen for the "evolution of expectation of functions" Kolmogorov equation as opposed to the "evolution of probability distributions" one are to the problems of finding expected hitting times and exit distributions. But these are both static problems.

Comment: As for thinking a bit more abstractly, the abstract thing that is interesting is the fact that the evolution of the expectation of functions and the evolution of probability distributions are connected, in that the linear operators appearing in them are formal adjoints of one another.

Comment: @Ian I thought that solutions to the heat equation are monotonic decreasing? And is the Kolmogorov equation somehow used for evolution of probability distributions? It seems purely about point estimates to me, so your second comment is interesting and is the kind of connection I'm looking for. Thanks btw.

Comment: No, solutions to the heat equation conserve the integral, by bringing "high" values down and "low" values up. In particular if $f(x)=x^2$ then $P_t f(0)$ is...either $t$ or $2t$, I forget which. Anyway, for the other connection, the relevant equation is called the Fokker-Planck equation in the physics literature. It is "a" forward Kolmogorov equation.